# What is the best way to enhance the back process when creating a Quote (for example)?

Tags: process-builder, quote, quotelineitem

I've noticed that in salesforce, there are certain "processes" that automatically trigger, like When Creating a Quote from an opportunity, It takes the opportunity line items, and generates quote line items, to do a quote, Is there a way to enhance or expand that process?

Comment: What kind of functionality are you looking to enhance in that process?

Comment: I created custom fields in Opportunity Item, and when I generate a quote, that pulls data from the Opportunity Items, to generate the Quote Items, I want it to pull the extra information, that I added...

Comment: Use the process builder for that or a trigger that execute on Quote